# Firing Facebook conversion pixel with Google Tag Manager and no confirmation page?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, conversion-tracking

I work on a website that is used to generate sales leads (www.first-european.co.uk). There are a few different forms on this website and all of these have confirmation pages, apart from the quote form (/customised-quote.html). This is the most heavily used form on the site, and to to track form submissions in Google Analytics I use Google Tag Manager's click listener for when the submit button is clicked.

To implement the Facebook pixel, I pasted it in to a custom HTML tag in GTM. My firing rules for this tag are the confirmation pages and when the "{{event}} equals submit_build_my_quote" (the quote form button click). It looks like the pixel is firing on the confirmation pages, but it doesn't seem to be firing for the button clicks.

Can anyone let me know the correct implementation, or if it's even possible to get this to work without a confirmation page?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So the Facebook pixel fires when you use a confirmation page, but does not fire when you try to fire it when the user clicks the submit button before the confirmation page loads?

Comment: @kevintechie in the case of the quote form, there is no confirmation page. The quote is displayed after the button is clicked but the URL doesn't change - hence tracking clicks for this goal instead of a confirmation page. The tag seems to be firing for the pages which do have confirmation pages, but not when the quote form submit button is clicked. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think my problem may be with the rule "{{event}} equals submit_build_my_quote". I don't think this is the correct way to tell GTM to fire the tag when the button is clicked. I'm a beginner at this so not sure what the correct rule(s) would be?..

Comment: How are you adding the submit_build_my_quote event to the dataLayer?

Comment: @kevintechie I have a UA event tracking tag with Category "Quote Form Clicks" and Action "{{element id}}".

I called the firing rule "Collect Quote Form Clicks" with the following conditions:

{{url}} contains /customised-quote.html and
{{event}} equals gtm.click

This allowed me to set up a goal in analytics by putting "Quote Form Clicks" and "submit_build_my_quote" as conditions.

I'm hoping this gives you the information you need as I don't know anything about data layers.

Cheers!

Comment: @kevintechie Just been reading about data layers and I think I've got my head around them. I need to add some code to the button, pushing an event to the data layer. I can then configure GTM to fire the Facebook pixel when the event occurs. The line of code for the submit button looks like <input type="Submit" id="submit_build_my_quote" value="Build my  quote >>" class="btn_build_quote btn-green"> at the moment. Could you tell me how I should edit this to push clicks on this button to the data layer? Thanks for your patience :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our discussion above, it seems like you are not detecting the form submit action and passing it to GTM. You can do this automatically with built-in GTM form submit auto event tracking.

In version 1 of GTM, add a [Form Submit Listener](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3420054?hl=en#FormSubmit) tag to fire on all pages.

In version 2 of GTM, add a new [Form Trigger](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716#FormSubmit).

Once you are detecting the form submit, you can then use your rules and tags to send form submit events to Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks @kevintechie. It looks like all conversions are now being tracked!